# How to count updated rows with laravel-excel

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I have implemented the **WithUpserts** concern but, i want to get the total of updated and inserted rows separately, how to achieve this ?

https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/batch-inserts.html#batch-upserts